# Crop a square shape around a centroid (numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, coordinates, crop, centroid

I have an numpy array image which contain circles. I extracted the whole x,y centroids (in pixels) of these circles (a numpy array as well). Now, I want to crop a square around each x,y centroid. 
Can someone instruct me how to solve it? 
Note that I didn't find any question in Stack that deals with crop around a specific coordinate.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If your centroid has indices `i,j` and you want to crop a square of size `2*w+1` around it on a numpy array `a`, you can do

```
a[i-w:i+w+1,j-w:j+w+1]
```

This is provided your indices are always more than `w` from the boundary.

If they're not, you can do

```
imin = max(0,i-w)
imax = min(a.shape[0],i+w+1)
jmin = max(0,j-w)
jmax = min(a.shape[1],j+w+1) 
a[imin:imax,jmin:jmax]
```

Comment: there is a more efficient way to clip your indices at the border using `np.where`. You could read around on stack to find it somewhere. If you'd like to read about this generally the terminology is 'numpy slicing'